# How to improve EF Core Performance if interacting with Oracle and PostgreSql in a single request to handle more than 200k records

Tags: postgresql, oracle, entity-framework-core, query-optimization, bulk-load

I have a .Net Core Web API endpoint which extracts the data from OracleDB and saves it into PostgreSQL DB. I am using the latest Entity Framework core and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL to connect to respective Database.

Internally in my service layer which API uses to connect to my Infra Layer, I have separate methods to call:

1. Call OracleRepository - In order to pull records from 5 tables (each in a diff method inside repository):

   1. Fetch Table A data
   2. Fetch Table B data.. and so on till Table E
2. Call PostgreSqlRepository -  In order to store data of each table (fetched from OracleDB) into  PostgreDB using Code First approach(again each in a diff method inside repository).

No of records in each table:

- A - 6.7k
- B - 113k
- C - 56k
- D - 5.8k
- E - 5.3k

Now all the above steps take around 45 seconds to complete. Any suggestions to improve the performance here.
Is there is a way to fetch data asynchronously from DB and store it? I have used Transient lifetime for both Oracle and Postgre Repository and all other services in my .net Core application.

Note: Each time I am truncating my PostgreSQL tables before inserting data (using the RemoveRange method of EfCore).

Comment: If you want to be fast, avoid those extra layers and write raw SQL. Use `COPY` for PostgreSQL and prepared statements otherwise.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am using raw SQL to pull data from Oracle but I am using code first in case of PostgreSQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Also can you explain COPY and prepared statements in PostgreSQL. Any reference would help as I am new to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Here are documentation links to [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) and [prepared statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html). Note that each API has its own methods to use prepared statements, and you don't have to do it using raw SQL.

Comment: EF Core is not for performance but for easiest CRUD. I would suggest to use third party library https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore, it will insert records in seconds (it also supports PostgreSQL COPY).

Comment: Please don't use Indian words here, they won't be understood elsewhere, and even less if you just have "L".

Answer (score 0):

When bulk-loading tables in relational databases, there's something to keep in mind.

By default, each `INSERT` query generates a [database transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). The [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) rules of the database require things to work correctly even if many concurrent database sessions are querying the table you're loading.  So, the automatic commit is time consuming.

You can work around this when bulk loading. The best way is with the [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) command. To use this, you'll extract your data from your source database (Oracle) and write it into a temporary CSV flat file on your file system.  That's fast enough.  Then you'll use queries like this to copy the file into the table. That's designed to be optimized around the transaction stuff.

```
COPY A FROM `/the/path/to/your/file.csv` DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

If you can't use COPY, know this.  If you batch up your INSERTs in explicit transactions, things work better.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO A (col, col) VALUES (val, val);
INSERT INTO A (col, col) VALUES (val, val);
INSERT INTO A (col, col) VALUES (val, val);
INSERT INTO A (col, col) VALUES (val, val);
INSERT INTO A (col, col) VALUES (val, val);
COMMIT;
```

things work a lot faster than if you do the inserts one by one. Batches of about 100 rows will typically get you a tenfold performance improvement.

In EF Core, you can do [transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) with code like so... This is pseudocode. It lacks exception handling and other things you need.

```cs
using var context = new WhateverContext();
const transactionLength = 100;

var rows = transactionLength;
var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

for each row in your input {
    context.Table.Add(new Row {  whatever });
    if ( --rows <= 0 ) {
        /* finish current transaction, start new one. */
        context.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Commit();
        transaction.Dispose();
        transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        rows = transactionLength;
    }
}
/* finish current transaction */
context.SaveChanges();
transaction.Commit();
transaction.Dispose();
```